# Is it possible to send readed sqlite from php and send it via socket?

Tags: php, sqlite

Is it possible to me to read data from sqlite with php and send it with php script to another server?

Ex: I have a "Local sqlite" database, i have a web. Basically i want someone can see some prefered content at my "Local sqlite database" from my web.
is that possible to do it with php tcp socket script?

PHP Read Local sqlite -> send the data to server through socket -> server listened and received the data -> Php show received data.

I can't do it right for now so i ask my problem here.

Comment: I know i can do it all with mysql, but the problem is i just want to keep the sqlite (I have the reason for it).

Comment: That is not possible exactly how you describe it, but close. If you really want to actively send the data from your local system to that web server, then you have to store it there until a client requests the data. Or you have to turn things round and make a subrequest in background when the web server gets a request. Before sending a reply (a web page) it fetches the data from your local system and uses it inside the reply. This however requires that the web server can reach the local system via network.

Comment: @arkascha ok thanks for the answer!

Comment: How come that I have the impression that neither the answer below nor my comment really helped to clear things up for you? :-)

Comment: @arkascha I just tryed to close this question.

Comment: Sure, all fine, as long as you made progress with your project. Would be a shame if you took the courage to ask here and did not really get help. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to switch from MySQL to SQLite if you already have working code.

You have to use either [SQLite extension](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.sqlite.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-sqlite.php).

Most queries do not need modification and can be used transparently between these databases.